# Dispatcher servlet and ResourceHttpRequestHandler conflict

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Webapp needs to serve static content and process rest calls on the seperate path.
In config I have registered ResourceHttpRequestHandler and Dispatcher Servlet:

```
    @Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/index.html").addResourceLocations("index.html");
}

    @Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherRegistration(DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet) {
    ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet);
    registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    registration.addUrlMappings("/rest/*");
    return registration;
}

@Bean(name = "dispatcherServlet")
public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet(WebApplicationContext context) {
    return new DispatcherServlet(context);
}
```

But the problem is that reource handler is not invoked if dispatcher servlet is registered, if I remove dispatcher servlet resource serving works.

How to get around this problem?

Maybe I should serve static content also with dispatcher servlet?

Comment: You say `But the problem is that reource handler is not invoked if dispatcher servlet is registered`. What happens instead? Which resource URLs are you trying to reach?

Comment: I cannot reach index.html anymore, but rest urls I can reach.